# How to avoid javascript injection while inline codes can be run in IIS 10?

Tags: security, iis, code-injection, content-security-policy, iis-10

I am trying to avoid users to write javascripts in my html using browsers inspector while my own inline and in page javascripts can be run.

I have tried these in IIS for Content-Security-Policy header:

```
default-src 'self' site.com ;style-src 'self' site.com 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'self' site.com 'unsafe-inline'
```

This will let my own codes to be run but users can inject javascripts in html and the following:

```
default-src 'self' site.com ;style-src 'self' site.com 'unsafe-inline';script-src 'self' site.com
```

Would not let users to inject codes but my own codes cant be run anymore.

How to avoid users to inject codes like alert('ok') in my html codes but have some inline and in page running javascripts codes using IIS?

Comment: How are your users capable of injecting their own JavaScript in the first place? Why isn't your application sanitizing input?

Comment: @Dai I mean writing an alert('ok') in my html codes not inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-script/) if you want to ensure that only your original inline code can run, then you can compute the hash of your inline JavaScript and put this in the CSP policy like so:

```
script-src js-cdn.example.com 'sha256-xzi4zkCjuC8lZcD2UmnqDG0vurmq12W/XKM5Vd0+MlQ='
```

Your browser developer tools console might compute the hash for you and output it in the console when inline scripts are blocked by CSP.